# BroadcastReceiver not responding

Tags: java, android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have a receiver that is called whenever an SMS is received

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private String prefName = "MyPref";
    private static final String NUMBER_KEY = "number";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // ---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";
        String Sender = null;
        if (bundle != null) {
            // ---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                Sender = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            }
            prefs = context
                    .getSharedPreferences(prefName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String phoneNumber = (String) prefs.getString(NUMBER_KEY, "");
            // If the sender of the SMS just received is the same as one chosen
            // earlier
            if (Sender.equals(phoneNumber)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "text message received",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // ---Launch the minderActivity even when the app is not in the
                // foreground---
                Intent minderActivityIntent = new Intent(context, Minder.class);
                minderActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(minderActivityIntent);
                // ---send a broadcast intent to update the SMS received in the
                // activity---
                Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
                broadcastIntent.setAction("SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION");
                broadcastIntent.putExtra("Sender", Sender);
                context.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I register the receiver in an activity called "minder" using a button

```
registerReceiver(intentReceiver, intentFilter);
```

In this "minder" activity I also have a `BroadcastReceiver`

```
private BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // ---gather up all the necessary user input---
        prefs = getSharedPreferences(prefName, MODE_PRIVATE);
        final Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnContacts);
        String phoneNumber = (String) prefs.getString(NUMBER_KEY, "");
        String messageChosen = (String) prefs.getString(MESSAGE_KEY, "");
        String delay = (String) prefs.getString(DELAY_KEY, "");
        String Sender = (String) intent.getExtras().getString("Sender");
        if (Sender.equals(phoneNumber)) {
            sendSMS(phoneNumber, messageChosen, delay);
        }
    }
};
```

All of the `permissions` are defined in the `manifest`.

Unfortunately when I test the receiver (i.e. send an sms to the phone, after the receiver has been registered, from the number that is defined as "phoneNumber") the app performs no action. Any ideas what is missing from my above code?

Comment: If you put a toast at the root of `onReceive()` (as in the very beginning) does that pop up?

Comment: Then your `if` isn't working, that's all. Make sure nothing differs.